# Discord bot switches account status to online when bot is running

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, chatbot

I have a discord bot that runs 24x7 but it changes my account status to online always. Even when I manually set it to invisible, my account switches back to online. I want to find a way to keep my account online only when I am actually online. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make yourself a command or an command line input which can edit the status

Command code:

```py
@bot.command
async def status(ctx, atype="None"):
    if atype in "None":
        pass
    elif atype in "dnd":
        await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.dnd)
    elif atype in "idle":
        await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle)
    elif atype in "online":
        await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online)
    elif atype in "offline" or type in "invincible":
        await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.offline)
    else:
        pass
```

The command line code:

```py
while True:
    atype = input("Enter action > ")

    if atype in "status dnd":
        await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.dnd)
    elif atype in "status idle":
        await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle)
    elif atype in "status online":
        await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online)
    elif atype in "status offline" or type in "status invincible":
        await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.offline)
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid action!")
```

atype stands for **action type**, because type is a python function

Hope this helps :)